# What does it mean if p-values differ

Tags: r, p-value, wilcoxon-signed-rank

I have a data for 322 items that are purchased between 2014 and 2018 by men and women.  If I ran a Wilcoxon Signed-Rank test with a Benjamini-Hochberg correction on the items purchased by men and women over the five year purpose I find that 83% are significant (<= 0.05) and 17% are not significant (>0.05).

But if I then calculate the average purchases of men and women over the five year and run the test again, I find no significance whatsoever.  I'm not sure which test I should use.  Shouldn't the average also show significance?

One is a test over each item over the five years and the other is an average over all items in each year.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In aggregate, there is neither reason nor guarantee that you will observe the same trend as when you split the comparison by some variable (*product* in your case). This phenomenon is called [Simpson's paradox](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson%27s_paradox).

Since you have only mentioned *significance*, and not the direction of the effects, it could also simply be the case that the trends observed within products cancel each other out when averaged.

Comment: Yep; Simpson's paradox is due to a form of [omitted variable bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omitted_variable_bias), which the OP may also find useful to read. However, comparing p-values is not especially helpful. See for example Gelman & Stern, [The Difference Between “Significant” and “Not Significant” is not Itself Statistically Significant](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/research/published/signif4.pdf)

Comment: Proper reference: Gelman A and Stern H (2006). 'The Difference between "Significant" and "Non-Significant" is itself not statistically significant'. *The American Statistician*, **60**, 328-331.